# generate views from meta data using STRING_AGG function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to generate the DDL for views from a table of meta data. Since every value for my_column_name maps to a single short_column_names the order is important. If they are both sorted by their individual columns the external name for the column will not match the internal name in the select statement. Other than concatenating a number in and removing to later, how can I sort both columns the same way?

To be more specific. I am creating a table to map the long SQL Server names to shorter names that I can query from Oracle. I am using Oracle 11.2.0.4, which has a limit of 30 characters for column and table names. The table and column names in the SQL Server instance that I am using can be as much as 128 characters. Hence, I need to create an updatable view to allow Oracle processes to query and update the SQL Server tables directly across a DB Link which is already setup.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[column_mapping](
    [my_schema_name]          [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [table_name]              [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [my_column_name]          [varchar](30)  NOT NULL,
    [short_column_name]       [varchar](30)  NULL,
    [sql_server_data_type]    [varchar](30)  NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(  [my_schema_name] ASC,
    [table_name]     ASC,
    [my_column_name] ASC ) ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.column_mapping 
       ( my_schema_name,        table_name, my_column_name,  short_column_name )
VALUES ( 'DBO',                 'COMPANY',  'NUMBER',        'CLIENTCODE' );

INSERT INTO dbo.column_mapping 
       ( my_schema_name,        table_name, my_column_name,  short_column_name )
VALUES ( 'DBO',                 'COMPANY',  'ACTIVE_STATUS', 'CLIENTSTATUS' );

INSERT INTO dbo.column_mapping 
       ( my_schema_name,        table_name, my_column_name,  short_column_name )
VALUES ( 'DBO',                 'COMPANY',  'LONG_NAME',     'FULLDESCRIPTION' );

INSERT INTO dbo.column_mapping 
       ( my_schema_name,        table_name, my_column_name,  short_column_name )
VALUES ( 'DBO',                 'COMPANY',  'SHORT_NAME',    'SHORTDESCRIPTION' );

INSERT INTO dbo.column_mapping 
       ( my_schema_name,        table_name, my_column_name,  short_column_name )
VALUES ( 'DBO',                 'COMPANY',  'SOURCE_ID',     'SOURCE_ID' );

INSERT INTO dbo.column_mapping 
       ( my_schema_name,        table_name, my_column_name,  short_column_name )
VALUES ( 'DBO',                 'COMPANY',  'SOURCE_SYSTEM', 'SOURCE_SYSTEM' );

COMMIT;
```

My query

```
SELECT my_schema_name, my_table_name, 
     STRING_AGG( my_column_name,  ',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_column_name ASC) AS my_column_names,
     STRING_AGG( short_column_name,     ',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_column_name ASC) AS short_column_names
FROM [dbo].[my_column_mapping]
GROUP BY my_schema_name, my_table_name
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Comment: Please have a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Use some online [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) or add a CREATE TABLE statement to your question and the desired result, that helps to get an accurate answer.

Comment: McNets - Have you used the STRING_AGG function to sort by a column other than the column that you are aggregating? Do you know if it is possible to sort by a column other than the column that is being aggregated?

Comment: I concur with @McNets assessment - we need more information. Until you comply with the site rules I am voting to close.

Comment: I added additional information. The LIST_AGG function from Oracle works in a similar way. Except in Oracle you can sort by any column. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Comment: The `STRING_AGG` syntax you are using in your example is exactly the one that's supposed to allow you to sort the aggregated values by *any* column. Could you please elaborate on how your current query doesn't work for you?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 does not support `string_agg()`

Comment: We use SQL Server 2014 in house. However, the instance that I am connecting to is in the Azure cloud. And its version is, Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Sep  9 2019 09:35:03   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. So I guess that that is SQL Server 2014. I guess I will just build my own function. The documentation is just not clear to me.

Comment: I am incredibly surprised a view wouldn't work for the Oracle side (meaning write the view on MS SQL and access that from Oracle). As an additional comment, please ensure you work to be nice, in keeping with the code of conduct. I have removed some incendiary text from some of this post.

Comment: jcolebrand, Define incendiary? I am asking how to use a particular function. Other than the statement that it doesn't exist in SQL Server 2014, no one else has really answered my original question. Perhaps, there is an obvious work around that I am unaware. Why focus on form over function?

Comment: @Gandolf989 I will be 100% honest. I removed a lot of text from your comments that others can't see. You were not very nice in them. You are more than welcome to use the help center to request SE staff review if you were nice with your words.

Comment: As for your specific non-answer, sometimes you need to wait for more people to be able to see a question. Answers aren't instant on StackExchange.

Comment: jcolebrand, When did I give you the impression that I wanted instant answers? I just wanted relevant posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried you example and added a join to the schemas, all_objects, and all_columns views. I was then able to add column_id and use that with the STRING_AGG function. Even though I used column_id in the ORDER BY on top, I did not get that order by with the column_id column and the STRING_AGG function. So as a_horse_with_no_name mentioned, in the version of SQL Server I am using, pre SQL Server 2017, the STRING_AGG function won't work. I need to do a nested loop to get the column names turned into a comma delimited list. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE to produce an ordering id column and use that to control order:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY my_column_name) AS [Order],
        my_schema_name, table_name, my_column_name,  short_column_name
    FROM #column_mapping
)

SELECT my_schema_name, table_name,
    STRING_AGG(my_column_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Order] ASC) AS my_columns,
    STRING_AGG(short_column_name, ', ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Order] ASC) AS short_column_names
FROM CTE
GROUP BY my_schema_name, table_name
```

Produces this result:

```
my_schema_name  |   table_name  |   my_columns                                                              |   short_column_names
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DBO             |   COMPANY     |   ACTIVE_STATUS, LONG_NAME, NUMBER, SHORT_NAME, SOURCE_ID, SOURCE_SYSTEM  |   CLIENTSTATUS, FULLDESCRIPTION, CLIENTCODE, SHORTDESCRIPTION, SOURCE_ID, SOURCE_SYSTEM
```

Because the CTE defines an order id for each record, when we order by this column in the STRING_AGG() function we will always get the matching column names.

Comment: Thanks HandyD. I will test your code and let you know how that works.